# boost::condition does not exist - condition is not a member of boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have been reading about boost condition variables for thread synchronization however I could only get access to the class `boost::condition_variable` and not `boost::condition` for which I get

```
'condition is not a member of boost'
```

any suggestions on what might be going on ? Do I need to download something. I am using VS2010 and boost 1.47

Comment: `boost::condition` does not exist. `boost::condition_variable` is what realizes... well, condition variables

Comment: @AndyProwl It should exist as a typedef in 1.47: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition

Comment: @Sancho: Woops! I didn't know that. Ok, thank you for correcting me. Sorry, I suck, etc. ;)

Comment: Did you include all necessary headers?

Comment: What headers are necessary for `boost::condition` ? I haven't added any headers for that purpose.

Comment: `#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition)

```
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>

typedef condition_variable_any condition;
```

The typedef condition is provided for backwards compatibility with previous boost releases.
Note that this has been **deprecated** in favor of `condition_variable_any` as of Boost 1.52.0.

Comment: yes that worked. So I believe `condition_variable_any` and `condition` are the same thing

Comment: And it appears that the correct (non-deprecated) type is `condition_variable_any`.